# UICollectionView embedded into an Eureka Custom Row

Tags: eureka-forms

We're planning to have a Left/Right scrollable photo stripe inside an [Eureka Form](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka).

This, in order to show multiple images, with the ability to add more.

Is [CustomRow](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#custom-rows) a good starting point to subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  I would recommend downloading their example project.  You can see how they build custom rows.